# Get first argument in live-template

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

Recently i was creating my own live-template, i was customizing `for` loop, here is how default for loop is given in live-template.

```
for(int $INDEX$ = 0; $INDEX$ < $LIMIT$; $INDEX$++) {
  $END$
}
```

but i want my method's first argument inplace of `$LIMIT$`, how can i do that?

```
public void getList(ArrayList<String> list)
{

}
```

then my for loop shoulde be

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size; i++) {
  ...
}
```

I have seen template of `logm`, but it is printing all arguments of method

```
groovyScript("'\"' + _1.collect { it + ' = [\" + ' + it + ' + \"]'}.join(', ') + '\"'", methodParameters())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following live template:

```
for(int $INDEX$ = 0; $INDEX$ < $VAR$.size(); $INDEX$++){
    $END$
}
```

Then go to right button "Edit variables" and put the following predefined methods in the expressions fields:

[image: Edit variables]

You can find all predefined methods in [Jetbrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/live-template-variables.html?origin=old_help)